# Push nested json values to array using node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, couchbase

I need to show my json results into nested array format:

```
{
    "state": [
        {
            "stateName": "tamilnadu"
        }
    ],
     "city": [
        {
            "cityName": "chennai"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code. I'm new in node development

```
exports.stateId = function (req, res) {
    state.find(req.body.countryId,  function() {
        var query = N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT stateId,stateName FROM travel _type='state'');

        myBucket.query(query, async function(err, result) {
            var state=[];
        await result.forEach(ele => {
        var item= {
            stateName:ele.stateName
        }
        if(ele.stateName != undefined)

        state.push(item);
    });

    res.send({state});
 });
 });
};


exports.cityId = function (req, res) {
    city.find(req.body.stateId,  function() {
        var query = N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT cityId,cityName FROM travel where _type="city"');
        myCluster.query(query, async function(err, result) {
            var city=[];
        await result.forEach(ele => {
        var item= {
            cityName:ele.cityName
        }
        if(ele.cityName != undefined)

        city.push(item);
    });
    res.send({city});
 });
 });
};
```

Currently i will get results like two different array. i need to merge json results into single nested data

Comment: could you show provide sample data which returned by the `result`?

Comment: both services returned separate json format {
        "state": [
            {
                "stateName": "tamilnadu"
            }
        ]
  }
  {
      "city": [
            {
                "cityName": "chennai"
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: make a json Object add these result to that json Object, according to your need

Comment: i dont know how to modify this code kindly help @ShubhamTiwari

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following data:

```
const data_1 =
{
  "state": [
    { "stateName": "tamilnadu" }
  ]
};
const data_2 =
{
  "city": [
    { "cityName": "chennai" } ]
};
```

and your desired object is:

```
{
    "state": [
        {
            "stateName": "tamilnadu"
        }
    ],
     "city": [
        {
            "cityName": "chennai"
        }
    ]
}
```

then you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method:

```
let desired = Object.assign({}, data_1, data_2);
console.log(`desired: `, desired)
```

Comment: How will i assign like const data_1 for  exports.cityId = function (req, res) {
    country.find(req.body.stateId,  function() {}

Comment: @NaveenKumar sorry, cannot understand what you want. Could you write source data and desired result?

Comment: I have two API exports services here both exports getting individual json data. i need to push state and city both into single exports and json data needed like nested array @StepUp

Comment: @NaveenKumar could you write source data and desired result? I mean a real example of json data - source and desired data.